# Jquery remove nth class from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove a dynamically assigned class from an element but do not know the name of that class.

For example if I have:

`<div id="myDiv" class="foo bar unknown"></div>`

In this case the unknown class will always be in position 3.

How can I achieve this using Jquery?

**more Info:**

```
function hideMyDiv(){
 var rnd=Date.now();

 $('#myDiv').addClass(rnd);

 setTimeout(function(){
 $('.'+rnd).hide();
  },10000);
}

function overRide(){
      $('#myDiv').3rdClass().remove();
  }
```

Comment: Why/how do you not know the name of a class you yourself are assigning?

Comment: [this sounds like an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: i have a function which will hide the div after a `setTimeout` occurs by adding class `x` then `$('.x').hide`, the action can be overRidden by removing `x` the same function can add another random class and so on

Comment: Do you know the other two classes for sure?  It may be easier to just set the className property directly to your intended value: `document.getElementById("myDiv").className = 'foo bar';`

Comment: This entire approach seems fragile at best and bug-prone for sure.  Instead of hijacking classes for this purpose, why don't you use proper data attributes?  For example, `<div id="myDiv" class="foo bar" data-hide="true"></div>`.

Comment: Well first of all, I'm not sure why you need to generate a random class.  Second of all, you _do_ know the name of the class from within the overRide() method.  It's rnd.  `$('#myDiv').removeClass(rnd);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing something wrong here, order of classes shouldn't matter.

But anyway you can do this

```
var parts = $('#myDiv').attr('class').split(' ');
$('#myDiv').removeClass(parts[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try writing a small helper method that will take the DOM element.

```
function removeClass(elem) {
    var c = elem.className.split(' '),
        cName;
    if (c && c.length > 0) {
        cName = c.splice(0, c.length - 1);
        elem.className = cName.join(' ');
    }
};
```

You can always enforce the condition you want to use.
**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxF25/)**

Answer (score 0):

Do this with jquery:

```
var _classes = $('a#somelink').attr('class').split(" ");
```

then you can loop thru that array and remove the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

In one line

```
$('#myDiv').removeClass($('#myDiv').attr('class').split(' ')[2]);
```

Explained:

```
$('#myDiv')     //jQuery selector
.removeClass   //removed the named class
$('#myDiv')     //jQuery selector
.attr('class') //get the class attribute of the element
.split(' ')    //split it into an array, with the perpetrator being a blank space aka ' ' 
[2]            //get the 3rd item in the array, remember it counts from 0, aka 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ...
```